# Unit testing array using items indexes

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I'm unit testing methods that are applied on an array and change its items states. Those items have different properties.
For example, my array is the following :

```
var array = [{state: false}, {status: true}, {health: true}];
```

After the method is applied (items order is relevant), I'm checking that the values have changed and are the ones I expect (I'm using mocha, chai) :

```
expect(array[0]).to.have.property('state', true);
expect(array[1]).to.have.property('status', false);
expect(array[2]).to.have.property('health', false);
```

Now, say that I want to add new energy items to my array :

```
var array = [{state: false}, **{energy: true}**,  {status: true}, **{energy: true}**, {health: true}];
```

I would have to changes my 0, 1, 2 indexes of my test to 0, 2, 4, and also add new tests for my new items.

What would be a good way of using (or not using) indexes so that each time I add new items types, I don't have to change all indexes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could test your result against a template that is structured in the way you expect. In the following code `expected` is the template.

```
var chai = require("chai");
var expect = chai.expect;

var a = [{state: false}, {energy: true}, {status: true}, {health: true}];

var expected = [
    {state: false},
    {energy: true},
    {status: true},
    {health: true}
];

for (var i = 0, item; (item = expected[i]); ++i) {
    expect(a[i]).to.eql(expected[i]);
}
```

You could also do:

```
expect(a).to.eql(expected);
```

but if you do this Mocha produces an utterly uninformative assertion failure message: `expected [ Array(4) ] to deeply equal [ Array(4) ]`. Performing the expects one by one in a loop allows you to get better messages. Like `expected { state: true } to deeply equal { state: false }`.

Comment: If you configure chai with chai.config.showDiff = true; and chai.config.truncateThreshold = 0; then the deep equal failure message will at least include the full objects. Unfortunately, it doesn't tell you where they are different.

Comment: I had tried turning on `showDiff` but did not realize that `truncateThreshold` was an issue. That's good to know. Thanks! I'm still not keen on having to eyeball the difference though.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin [chai-things](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-things) for chai which makes this really readable:

```
[{ a: 'cat' }, { a: 'dog' }].should.contain.a.thing.with.property('a', 'cat')
```

Comment: In my case, I can have items that have the same properties multiple times in my array, and their position in the array is also important, therefore this test isn't enough.